# How do I make a custom Keras loss function known to the Scikit-Learn GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to find hyper-parameters for my Keras model, which contains a custom loss function, with [gridsearchcv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

When I run this manually (outside of a gridsearch), it works. However, if I run gridsearchcv on it and do this in parallel, it seems like there is some problem with the serialization that the Koby backend performs, when setting the parameter `n_jobs=-1`.

This is how I set up my custom loss function:

```
from keras import backend as K

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # perform some calculations using K
    # ...
    return 1 - K.mean(score)
```

This is my model function, which takes some parameters from the grid search:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input

def create_model(hidden_layers, activation, last_activation, optimizer, drop_rate, initializer, units, input_dim):
    # some layer definitions of inputs and outputs
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
    return model
```

Finally, how I put it together:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

skfs = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
parameters = {'hidden_layers': [...],
              'activation':[...],
              'last_activation': [...],
              'optimizer':[...],
              'drop_rate':[...],
              'initializer':[...],
              'units':[...],
              'input_dim': [...]
             }
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=256, verbose=0)
classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters, cv=skfs, scoring=score, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, return_train_score=True)
results = classifier.fit(X, y, callbacks=early_stopping)
```

When I execute the above code, I get an exception saying `my_loss` function is unknown. However, if I change it to (see `n_jobs` paramter):

```
classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters, cv=skfs, scoring=score, verbose=1, n_jobs=1, return_train_score=True)
```

it works. I believe that I must somehow propagate my own function. How can I do this?

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm having the same trouble with `BaggingRegressor` which it seems use the same architecture as `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: I ended up using another approach to parallelization: joblib. I basically implemented my own grid search based on [repeated stratified k fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html), because I realized that I needed some data balancing within the grid search, not prior to it. However, perhaps it could work if you tried to match [their implementation of mse](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py). Finally, [Custom object Scopes](https://keras.io/utils/#customobjectscope) might be exactly, what you need.